# Troubleshooting a tkinter GUI that will pull html code and displays it from websites?

Tags: python, html, user-interface, tkinter

l have to develop an interactive program which lets its users select from
several ranked HTML lists and using widgets to pick out certain HTML code to display the current 2nd position in each lists. Each widget is too show a differnet list from a different HTML website each time. I have set up all my widgets and my GUI but I am unsure on how to complete this task of each widget pulling HTML code and displaying it in a window.

The main things I am having problems with are, pulling HTML code from a live website and displaying this using my radiobutton widgets. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is the code that I have completed so far

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Runners Up")
root.config(background = "#f0f0f0")

test_status0 = BooleanVar()
test_status1 = BooleanVar()
test_status2 = BooleanVar()
test_status3 = BooleanVar()
test_status4 = BooleanVar()
 

#Label Frame for Radio Buttons
radiobuttonsframe = LabelFrame(root, relief = 'groove', font = 'Arial',
                              borderwidth = 5)
radiobuttonsframe.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)


#Picture Label Frame
PicFrame = LabelFrame(root, relief = 'groove', borderwidth = 5)
PicFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)


#Display Frame (Runner Up)
RunnerFrame = LabelFrame(root, relief = 'groove', borderwidth = 5, font = 'Arial',
                         text = 'Runner Up')
RunnerFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)


#Display Frame (Full List)
ListFrame = LabelFrame(root, relief = 'groove', borderwidth = 5, font = 'Arial',
                       text = 'Full List')
ListFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)


#Importing Photo
Picture1 = PhotoImage(file="Secondplace.gif")
Label(PicFrame, image=Picture1).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)



#Frames for each widget
btnFrame = LabelFrame(radiobuttonsframe, relief = 'groove',
                      font = 'Arial', borderwidth = 2, text = 'Current Runner Ups', background="#f0f0f0")
btnFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

btnFramePrev = LabelFrame(radiobuttonsframe, relief = 'groove',
                      font = 'Arial', borderwidth = 2, text = 'Previous Runner Ups', background="#f0f0f0")
btnFramePrev.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=50)

updaterBtn = LabelFrame(radiobuttonsframe, relief = 'groove',
                      font = 'Arial', borderwidth = 2, background="#f0f0f0")
updaterBtn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)


#Button Music Runner ups
MusicButton = Radiobutton(btnFrame, text="Top Album Charts [Title and Artist]",
                     height=2, width=50, value = test_status1, command = test1)
MusicButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Button for Movie Runner ups
MovieButton = Radiobutton(btnFrame, text="Movie Charts [Title and Production]",
                     height=2, width=50, value = test_status2, command = test1)
MovieButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Button for games runner ups
GamesButton = Radiobutton(btnFrame, text="Game Charts [Title and Players]",
                     height=2, width=50, value = test_status3, command = test1)
GamesButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Button for Medal runner ups
MedalButton = Radiobutton(btnFramePrev, text="Medal 2001 [Name and Votes]",
                   height=2, width=50, value = test_status4, command = test1)
MedalButton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)


#Scroll Bar for full list of winners
ListScroll = ScrolledText(ListFrame, width=40, height=10)
ListScroll.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Text Box for our main Runners Up
RunnersText = Text(RunnerFrame, width=50, height=10)
RunnersText.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Update and Show Source Buttons
Update = Button(updaterBtn, text="Update", height=2, width=10)
Update.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
ShowSource = Button(updaterBtn, text="Show Source", height=2, width=10)
ShowSource.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)
root.mainloop()
```

\EDIT//
I've figured out to run the buttons but now I am having trouble actually getting the HTML text to display in my text box.

Here is my attempt at trying that:

```
def MusicRunner():
    RunnersText.delete(0.0, END)
    site = 'Official Charts'
    feed_web = download('https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/')
    items = findall(r'<body class="sticky-nav" style \b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>', feed_web, flags=MULTILINE|DOTALL)
    num = findall(r'<span class= "position">"2"</span>',feed_web, flags=MULTILINE|DOTALL)   
    RunnersText.insert(INSERT, num)
```